# Unable to code with threading as an alternative to fork()

Tags: c, multithreading, fork

I am coding on Windows, so fork() is not available. Now, i need to run execl(), but it is an end point of my program! I thought of creating a separate thread to run execl(), which is created successfully, and runs well also. But still my program comes to an end after thread is over. 
Function running thread--It is inside class wScoreget:-

```
     int refresh_score_now(){
            pthread_t t;
            if(pthread_create(&t,NULL,s.basicgetscore,&s)==-1){
                                printf("Error: wScoreget:3");
                                exit(4);
                                }

            void *a;
            if(pthread_join(t,&a)==-1){
                printf("Error: wScoreget: 4");
                exit(4);
                printf("Running thread.\n");
                getch();
            }

        }
```

Calling from main:-

```
            int main(){

    wScoreget new_ws;
    new_ws.refresh_score_now();
    printf("reached to the end\n");
    getch();
    }
```

I am expecting console to print- "reached to the end"
But on execl() it exits. 
NOTE: execl() is running curl. Its output is going to a text file. Now, if stdout is changed, curl shows download timing and other data on the console. THAT data comes to console anyways.

Is there a way I can do this without using CreateProcess? And if I use CreateProcess, which libraries do I have to install on Windows(I am using MingW + Codeblocks).

Comment: I've added a C language tag.  Change if this not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `spawn` or `posix_spawn`. It should replace fork + exec.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_%28computing%29
- http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn